# Running php-fpm with httpd 2.4.4 in CentOS 6.4

Tags: centos, httpd, php-fpm

I upgraded to httpd 2.4.4 from the httpd 2.2 that shipped with CentOS/RHEL 6.4.  I'm running into an error trying to serve Roundcube mail using php-fpm.  We tried a number of solutions on #httpd at Freenode.  I would *greatly* appreciate any insight.  It worked well with httpd 2.2.

These instructions were followed so far:  https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM

The error I get is `Forbidden:  You don't have permission to access / on this server`.  The error log says:

```
[Fri Sep 06 15:26:23.542241 2013] [autoindex:error] [pid 16868:tid 140266652563200] [client 129.105.171.78:50823] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/roundcubemail/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

VirtualHost in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mail.mydomain.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/roundcubemail
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/domain.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/domain.key
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/roundcubemail/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/httpd/conf.d/roundcubemail.conf

```
<Directory "/var/www/roundcubemail/">
    Options -Indexes
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

/var/www/roundcubemail/.htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset     UTF-8
AddType text/x-component .htc

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag        display_errors  Off
php_flag        log_errors      On
# php_value     error_log       logs/errors

php_value       upload_max_filesize     5M
php_value       post_max_size           6M
php_value       memory_limit            64M

php_flag        zlib.output_compression         Off
php_flag        magic_quotes_gpc                Off
php_flag        magic_quotes_runtime            Off
php_flag        zend.ze1_compatibility_mode     Off
php_flag        suhosin.session.encrypt         Off

#php_value      session.cookie_path             /
php_flag        session.auto_start      Off
php_value       session.gc_maxlifetime  21600
php_value       session.gc_divisor      500
php_value       session.gc_probability  1

# http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=30766
php_value       mbstring.func_overload  0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^favicon\.ico$ skins/larry/images/favicon.ico
# security rules
RewriteRule \.git - [F]
RewriteRule ^/?(README(.md)?|INSTALL|LICENSE|CHANGELOG|UPGRADING)$ - [F]
RewriteRule ^/?(SQL|bin) - [F]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
# replace 'append' with 'merge' for Apache version 2.2.9 and later
#Header append Cache-Control public env=!NO_CACHE
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>

FileETag MTime Size

<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
Options -Indexes
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's PHP, isn't it? Your `VirtualHost` should also contain:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Comment: Thanks.  Now I'm getting `[Fri Sep 06 16:25:13.755424 2013] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 19171:tid 140695255897856] [client 129.*.*.*:51822] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'` Once index.php is put in.  This looks like a common problem?

Answer (score 0):

After adding

```
 DirectoryIndex index.php
```

The error

```
 Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'
```

Means that index.php can't be found in `/var/www/roundcubemail` are you sure that it is there ? For roundcube it is a good practise to use the `public_html` folder to keep sensitive files out of reach, so your index.php might be there instead.